# NSRegularExpression - Match version number

Tags: ios, regex, swift, nsregularexpression

In order to check if a string is a version number thanks to `NSRegularExpression`, I created the following pattern:

`let pattern = "^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+))?(?:\\.(\\d+))?(?:\\.)?$"`

It works pretty well and allows me to match:

1. `"8"`,
2. `"12."`,
3. `"8.3"`,
4. `"8.10."`,
5. `"8.2.5"`,
6. and `"8.2.28."`.

However, when I try to improve it with the following pattern, it doesn't work anymore.

`let pattern = "^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)){0,2}(?:\\.)?$"`

My tests 5 and 6 don't work anymore. Any ideas why?

Comment: are you looking for matching end string from whole string ? or match any number string from whole string in any position ?

Comment: @None: I wanna match only strings which contains only one version numbers. The first pattern I wrote works well, I just want to improve it to be shorter and more readable.

Comment: it works.`https://www.regex101.com/r/fJ6cR4/4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hum... I just figured out what was the problem.

So both patterns match the same whole strings. However the capturing parentheses don't have the same behaviors in both patterns.

If I apply the pattern `^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+))?(?:\\.(\\d+))?(?:\\.)?$` on the string `"1.2.3"`, the `NSTextCheckingResult` obtained has a `numberOfRanges` of 4.

If I apply the pattern `^(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)){0,2}(?:\\.)?$` on the string `"1.2.3"`, the `NSTextCheckingResult` obtained has a `numberOfRanges` of 3. It appears that during the second pass into `(?:\\.(\\d+)){0,2}`, a new range isn't created. Instead, the previous range is overwritten.

It explains why my unit tests didn't work anymore. :-)

Thanks to everybody for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

actually i have tried following things and its working fine. i think issue related you expect the line start with digit and end with matched digit so might be a problem. Here i tried following things.

```
NSString* aString = @"8 iokdsa da 12. dasdsadaasd 8.3 cccc 8.10. rrr 8.2.5 rrrrr 8.2.28.";


    NSRegularExpression* tableRegex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:@"(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)){0,2}(?:\\.)?" options:0 error:NULL] ;
    [tableRegex enumerateMatchesInString:aString options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length]) usingBlock:^(NSTextCheckingResult *match, NSMatchingFlags flags, BOOL *stop){

        NSLog(@"Print : %@",[aString substringWithRange:match.range]);


    }];
```

Output :

Print : 8

Print : 12.

Print : 8.3

Print : 8.10.

Print : 8.2.5

Print : 8.2.28.

If you want just end keyword to matched then attached $ signed at end of above expression like as below.

```
(\\d+)(?:\\.(\\d+)){0,2}(?:\\.)?$
```

Hope this help you.

Comment: Like I explained in my question's comments, I wanna match only strings which contains only one version numbers (no others characters). That's why I added `^` and `$`.